# How to share product image and details in social media in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.2.5, social-buttons

I want to share product image and details to social media in Magento 2 using addthistool.

We have added http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5b30cd59923bb69c js in header part

**Phtml**

> Custom/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/social-share.phtml

```
<div class="st-addthis-custom addthis_toolbox">
<ul class="sharing-links custom_images">
    <li>
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook link-facebook" title="Share on Facebook">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="addthis_button_twitter link-twitter" title="Share on Twitter">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="addthis_button_linkedin link-linkedin" title="Share on Linkedin">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Block**

> Custom/Module/view/layout/frontend/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.view.addthis.custom.social-share" template="Custom_Module::product/view/social-share.phtml" before="-" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: @ShoaibMunir i am using  https://www.addthis.com/ plugin.But how can i pass product details to facebook or any other social media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook reads website `og meta` tags so you need to add og tags in head of your magento

Example tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My product title"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ABC Site"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/example.html"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/k/mke-08-_1_.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="My product description"/>
```

Facebook crawler crawls your website and reads these tags from page. And if you want your page to re-crawl then you need to request for re-crawl from this tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: I have added meta property as u have defined but when i debug the url unable to get few property such as og:type,og:description,og:image Can u provide me solution for that

Comment: u can check in file vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\opengraph/general.phtml it is already set but not displayed in facebook

Comment: is it appearing on website browser source?

Comment: Yes it is appearing

Comment: it should work then, can you share your product url?

Comment: I am working on local server is there any configuration require for this ?

Comment: How can facebook fetch from local server? your website should have public access to share something on facebook, it wont fetch data from local server

Comment: And what about staging server/production server?

Comment: since staging server and production server has public access, facebook will fetch data from it, and you can test stating and production url from here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: I think staging and production url should contain domain for connection to facebook. Right?

Comment: yes, you should have public domain from which facebook can fetch data

Comment: Okay thanks for help

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it is helpful to you, your post is still open, you need to mark correct

Comment: Thanks Parthavi. +1 on your question

Answer (score 1):

There is a free extension available, You can use it :

https://marketplace.magento.com/magebuzz-socialshare.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-share/?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=mageplaza&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&utm_content=Social%20Share

Comment: Can u explain in detail regarding developer section

Comment: Have you installed the above extension?

Comment: I am using https://www.addthis.com/ this plugin